# Eager loading doesn't work with BackgroundService

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, eager-loading, background-service, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm trying to load related entities in a console application that runs a `BackgroundService`,
but it doesn't load related entities, I have had this problem for hours now and I just noticed it happens only in the `BackgroundService`, tried the same `DbContext` in a web application by injecting the DbContext class in the Index page model, without a problem.

Here's the code from the console application:

the Background Service:

```
public class MyService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public MyService(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

   protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    { 
                     //Jobs always empty!
        var theBatch = _context.Batches.Include(x => x.Jobs).FirstOrDefault();
     } 
}
```

the program file:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        await host.RunAsync();
    }

    static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
       {
           services.AddLogging()
         .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options
         .UseSqlServer(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")))

         .AddHostedService<MyService>()
         .BuildServiceProvider();
       });
}
```

I'm using .NET 5 and EF Core 5.0.12

Comment: Out of my curiosity. Why are you building the service provider? Also have you tried access the context anywhere else outside of the contractor, like in `Execute` and just use the constructor for assignment?

Comment: Not for a thing I need, copied without my notice!

Comment: I don't understand your proposal, I already did that: I assigned the context in the constructor, and accessed it in the `Execute` method

Comment: But your example shows using the include in the constructor.  Are you saying that even if you access Batches in execute it is empty?

Comment: Aaah, I see. I copied the code from my editor in the wrong places here!

Comment: I just realized something. You are explicitly injected a scoped DbContext into a `IHostedService` which is usually a singleton. Have you considered creating the scope within the hosted service?

Comment: Sorry, modified the code

Comment: Yes, and I expected to throw shorter lifetime exception but it didn't. I will try creating the scope tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm writing this while I'm really angry for the hours and the effort spent on this problem, I don't know who to blame, Microsoft or the person who installed EF 6 in .NET core project. Microsoft made it difficult to find out the source of the problem.

I was using `Include` from `System.Data.Entity` namespace not `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

I figured it out by a mere coincidence, I used `FirstOrDefaultAsync` without a specific reason, and got this weird exception:

> 'The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement
> IDbAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement
> IDbAsyncQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous
> operations.

When I looked at it, I found that I was using the wrong namespace for `FirstOrDefaultAsync` (`System.Data.Entity` instead of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`)
when I changed the namespace, everything worked!

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work as written.  So double-check your configuration.  As @Nkosi points out you should use shorter scopes, but putting one scope in your ExecuteAsync isn't enough, as the Task it returns has the same lifetime as the BackgroundService instance.

Anyway here's a complete repro that works fine in .NET 6.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        using IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        await host.RunAsync();
    }

    static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
       {
           services.AddLogging()
                    .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options
                    .UseSqlServer(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")))
                    .AddHostedService<MyService>()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();
       });
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }
#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
    public DbSet<Batch> Batches { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Job> Jobs{ get; set; }
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
}

public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Batch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; } = new HashSet<Job>();
}

public class MyService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public MyService(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        var batch = new Batch();
        batch.Jobs.Add(new Job() );

        context.Batches.Add(batch);
        context.SaveChanges();
        context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
    }



    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var theBatch = await _context.Batches.Include(x => x.Jobs).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(theBatch.Jobs.Count);
    }
}
```